# Downsampling a 2d MATRIX in matlab, by taking average block wise

Tags: matlab, matrix, downsampling

Say I have a matrix A, which is of dimension 4x4.

Now I want to downsample this matrix by a factor 2 to get a new matrix B of dimension 2x2.

I want to downsample in the following way :

Let A be

```
 1     5     9    13
 2     6    10    14
 3     7    11    15
 4     8    12    16
```

I want B to be

```
3.5000   11.5000
5.5000   13.5000
```

To get B(1,1) = I take mean (1, 5, 2 and 6)

To get B(1,2) = I take mean (9, 13, 10 and 14)

To get B(2,1) = I take mean (3, 7, 4 and 8) and so on.

So for every element in B, I take the corresponding 2x2 block from A and take the mean of it.

In my case, the matrix A is of large dimension. 
Also, the downsampling factor could be arbitrary.

For example,
A =

```
 1     7    13    19    25    31
 2     8    14    20    26    32
 3     9    15    21    27    33
 4    10    16    22    28    34
 5    11    17    23    29    35
 6    12    18    24    30    36
```

For downsampling of size 3/2.

Matrix B will be of size 4x4.

For every B unit I would have to take non-overlapping 1.5x1.5 blocks of A.

For example,

B(1,1) = mean(1, 0.5x7, 0.5x2, 0.5x8)

B(2,1) = mean(0.5x2, 0.5x8, 3, 9)

B(3,1) = mean(4, 0.5x10, 0.5x5, 0.5x11)

B(4,1) = mean(0.5x5, 0.5x11, 6, 12)

and so on.

Is there a faster way to do this without for loops?

Comment: The `(1,1)` element of B should be 3.5 right?

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
A = [1     5     9    13;
 2     6    10    14;
 3     7    11    15;
 4     8    12    16];

B = ones(2)/4;

out = conv2(A,B,'valid');

%{
out = [3.5000    7.5000   11.5000;
4.5000    8.5000   12.5000;
5.5000    9.5000   13.5000];
%}
```

This gives you a little more than what you asked for, but you can throw away the information you don't need. For this case, you'd only be interested in out(1,1) ,  out(1,3)  out (3,1)  and out(3,3)

Comment: You can complete the answer by doing `out = out(1:2:end,1:2:end);`.  This is pretty much the same approach I took in the duplicate post.

Comment: Oh shoot @rayryeng I didn't even think to look for a duplicate haha that's good you marked it.

Comment: @Benoit_11 - Haha no worries.  I only knew about it because I answered a similar question a couple of days ago.  If I didn't do that, I wouldn't have marked as a duplicate because I wouldn't know where to look!  I still upvoted both answer regardless.

Comment: @Benoit_11 - BTW, lots of activity on my question.  I've revised my post to take advantage of `scatter`.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @rayryeng Awesome then glad to help! I'll follow the updates on your question :)

Comment: @rayryeng : I edited the question now. I want arbitary downsampling factor.

Comment: @AdithyanIlangovan - That's a new question all together.  Editing won't guarantee that it will be reopen.  Please make a new question.

Comment: @rayryeng Sorry, I am new to this. I just added an extra example to make it more clear. I wanted arbitary non-integer downsampling in the first place.
Should I open a new question? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox you can make use of [blockproc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html):

```
fun = @(block_struct) mean2(block_struct.data) * ones(size(block_struct.data));
B = blockproc(A,[2 2],fun);

B = reshape(unique(B),2,[])
```

Output:

```
A =

     1     5     9    13
     2     6    10    14
     3     7    11    15
     4     8    12    16


B =

          3.5         11.5
          5.5         13.5
```

Where you can replace the block size by any factor you want. Note that for non-integer factors MATLAB will truncate them.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly for integer downsampling factors. I want non-integer sampling factors. I edited question now, please see.